# How to select a specific child node and add new Child node in it

Tags: c#, xml

I am an XML beginner and really need your help due to this issue already blocked me for hours.

I am using C# and write some code to control my XML.
Right now I have a

`string StrSec = "Scetion A"`

My Code is like below:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(myPath);
```

in here i want to do something like this:

```
Check each of sections in current XML, if section.name == StrSec
```

then put the new case into that specific section

```
if section.name != StrSec, then put case into Section B
```

```
XmlElement newCase = doc.CreateElement("case");
XmlElement newName= doc.CreateElement("name");
newName.InnerText = "Case 4";
XmlElement newDes= doc.CreateElement("description");
newDes.InnerText = "something here";

newCase .AppendChild(newName);
newCase .AppendChild(newDes);
```

This is current XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite>
    <sections> 
        <section>
            <name>Section A</name>
            <cases>
                <case>
                    <name>Case 1</name>
                    <description>something here</description>
                </case>
                <case>
                    <name>Case 2</name>
                    <description>something here</description>
                </case>                    
            </cases>
        </section>
        <section>
            <name>Section B</name>
            <cases>
                <case>
                    <name>Case 3</name>
                    <description>something here</description>
                </case>                
            </cases>
        </section>          
    </sections>
</suite>
```

The final result should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <suite>
        <sections> 
            <section>
                <name>Section A</name>
                <cases>
                    <case>
                        <name>Case 1</name>
                        <description>something here</description>
                    </case>
                    <case>
                        <name>Case 2</name>
                        <description>something here</description>
                    </case>
                    <case>
                        <name>Case 4</name>
                        <description>something here</description>
                    </case>
                </cases>
            </section>
            <section>
                <name>Section B</name>
                <cases>
                    <case>
                        <name>Case 3</name>
                        <description>something here</description>
                    </case>                
                </cases>
            </section>          
        </sections>
    </suite>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XDocument instead of XmlDocument (as it's slightly easier to work with):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(text);
foreach (var section in doc.Descendents("section").Where(x => x.Element("name").Value == "Section A"))
{
    section.Element("cases").Add(
        new XElement("case",
            new XElement("name", "Case 4"),
            new XElement("description", "something here")
        )
    );
}
```

You can find further documentation on XElement [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/xelement-class-overview).

Comment: Hi Canton7, thanks for your reply, my example is kind sample, the actual case is inside the case, i still have several child node and sub child node, how to create a child node inside the case, if you could tell me a little bit more i can try other part then : ) cant check right now due to i am already home. will try it tomorrow.

Comment: @suppermanzz You can traverse a hierarchy of elements using `.Element("first").Element("second").Element("third")` (using `.Elements("name")` if there are multiple children, and then looping over the result), or go straight for the innermost elements (assuming it's unambiguous) using `.Descendents("third")`. You can see how I did that above - I use `.Descendents("section")` to find the `section` element inside the `sections` one, and then I use `.Element("name")` and `.Element("cases")` to explore its children.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try tomorrow. After reading your comment I think XDocument is much more readable and easy to understand ; )